# record type out parameter function not working

Tags: postgresql

when I exceute the function schemaA.ad_update with payrecord.paydetails.ad_seq getting below error.

```
Error : missing FROM-clause entry for table "paydetails".
```

I thought because of paydetails is coming from function of "schemaB" got this error hence I have used as  payrecord.schemaB.paydetails.ad_seq.

```
Error: cross-database references are not implemented: payrecord.schemaB.paydetails.ad_seq
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schemaA.ad_update(p_custno varchar, custseq numeric)
 RETURNS record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    declare
    payrecord              RECORD;
    ppdate timestamp:=current_timestamp;
    ppseq numeric:=1;
   deamtpaid numeric;
  begin

payrecord:= schemaB.adf_function(  p_custno,
                                 custseq,
                                 deamtpaid, 
                                 ppdate,
                                 ppseq
                                );  
deamtpaid:=payrecord.amtpaid;                                                                                                                   

          update paymenttable
          set dps_seq = 15
          where ad_seq = payrecord.paydetails.ad_seq  -- As you suggested
  end $function$;


create or replace  function schemaB.adf_function(custno     IN VARCHAR,
                                        custseq IN NUMERIC,
                                        amtpaid      inout NUMERIC,
                                        paydate       IN TIMESTAMP(0),
                                        paidseq     IN NUMERIC,
                                        paydetails     out paymenttable) RETURNS RECORD as
      $adf_function$
    declare
    c_seq               numeric := 1;
    m_seq                numeric := 1;
    v_custno           VARCHAR;
    v_clsid    numeric;
    v_otamt    NUMERIC := 0;
    v_pending   NUMERIC := 0;
    v_remark                VARCHAR(255);
    v_flag      boolean;
    pptrecord RECORD;
begin
select * from accountinfo(custno ) into v_flag;

if not v_flag then

select * from mstr_function(v_custno,
                                paidseq,
                                c_seq,
                                v_remark,
                                v_pending,
                                v_otamt,
                                paydate,
                                m_seq,
                                v_clsid) into pptrecord;


 v_pending:= pptrecord.p_pending;
 paydetails:= pptrecord.p_mstr_record; -- where p_mstr_record is out parameter in  mstr_function as p_mstr_record     out paymenttable
 v_otamt:= pptrecord.p_otamt;                               
 amtpaid := v_pending;

 end $adf_function$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: @Ram Did you modify the code before posting it? It looks a bit like.. For example, ```deamtpaid``` is not declared. Anyways, I'm going to have a shot at the question

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at the function `adf_function`: it is returning a record with fields `amtpaid` (type `numeric`) and `paydetails` (type `paymenttable`).

Thus assigning its result to a variable of type `paymenttable` can not work (since there is missing one column and also `amtpaid` will be assigned to the first field of the type and therefore following values are shifted and do not longer match the specified types, compare this to your error `value too long for type character varying(20)`).

So it is necessary to declare `payrecord` as of type `record`. Your error `record "payrecord" has no field "ad_seq"` comes up, because `payrecord` has only 2 fields: `amtpaid` and `paydetails` (which itself is composite). Thus you need to access all fields of your `paymenttable` record inside the `payrecord` as `payrecord.paydetails.<field_name>`.

**Conclusion:**

1. declare `payrecord` as of type `record`
2. acces the `ad_seq` as `(payrecord.paydetails).ad_seq`

**Helpful debugging note:**

To find the reason for such errors, it might be useful to manually execute the "bad" function call on its own and have a look at the result:

```sql
SELECT * FROM adf_function(<place your given parameters here>);
```

In the result you should be able to see which fields have which types and if they are nested.

**EDIT**

It might be necessary to use parantheses around the composite type variable. For further information, see the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-ACCESSING

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. As I am unable add in comments section whatever I tried. I have edited.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. I for got to mention one thing both the functions are in different schema.
FUNCTION schemaA.ad_update
function schemaB.adf_function
I tried whatever you suggested.

payrecord record;
payrecord:= schemaB.adf_function( p_custno
update paymenttable set dps_seq = 15 where ad_seq = payrecord.paydetails.ad_seq;

ErrMsg: missing FROM-clause entry for table "paydetails".
I thought because of different schema got this error hence I have used as payrecord.schemaB.paydetails.ad_seq
ErrMsg: cross-database references are not implemented: payrecord.schemaB.paydetails.ad_seq

Comment: Wait.. how did there suddenly appear an ```UPDATE```? Please add your recent code and the error message via editing to your original question. This is not readable in the comment section

Comment: I have edited my original question. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-ACCESSING